# Ember.js dynamic routes not resolving in test, but work in production

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-qunit

So, I'm trying to use the Twitter-style URL syntax, allowing a user to go to `example.com/quaunaut` to visit the user page of the user with the username 'quaunaut'. I was able to accomplish this via:

**app/router.js**

```
export default Router.map(function() {
  this.route('users.show', { path: '/:user_username' });
});
```

**app/routes/users/show.js**

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('user', { username: params.user_username }).then(function(result) {
      return result.get('firstObject');
    });
  },

  serialize: function(model) {
    return { user_username: model.get('username') };
  }
});
```

Now, when live or run via `ember s`, this works fantastically. However, in tests, it seems for some reason to not resolve.

```
var application, server, USERS;
USERS = {
  'example1': [{
    id: 1,
    username: 'example1'
  }],
  'example2': [{
    id: 2,
    username: 'example2'
  }]
};

module('Acceptance: UsersShow', {
  beforeEach: function() {
    application = startApp();

    server = new Pretender(function() {
      this.get('/api/users', function(request) {
        return [
          201,
          { 'content-type': 'application/javascript' },
          JSON.stringify(USERS[request.queryParams.username])
        ];
      });
    });
  },

  afterEach: function() {
    Ember.run(application, 'destroy');
    server.shutdown();
  }
});

test('visiting users.show route', function(assert) {
  visit('/example1');

  andThen(function() {
    assert.equal(currentPath(), 'users.show');
    assert.equal(find('#username').text(), 'example1');
  });
});
```

Which results in the following test results:

```
Acceptance: UsersShow: visiting users.show route
    ✘ failed
         expected users.show
    ✘ failed
         expected example1
```

So, any ideas why `currentPath()` isn't resolving? If you also have any recommendations for better means to implement what I'm looking to do here, I'm certainly open to it.

Comment: What is the value of your `storeConfigInMeta`?

Answer (score 0):

Your `visit` syntax isn't quite right, should be:

```
test('visiting users.show route', function(assert) {
  visit('/example1').then(function() {
    assert.equal(currentPath(), 'users.show');
    assert.equal(find('#username').text(), 'example1');
  });
});
```

Comment: andThen simply waits for all promises(as opposed to a specific promise) to finish. Your method still ends up with `currentPath()` being `undefined`, so I don't think this is it.